# Как программно закрыть Android-приложение полностью?

Tags: java, android

Как программно закрыть приложение полностью, т.е. удалить его из памяти так, как сделал бы сам андроид при нехватке ресурсов?

Comment: т.е. как приложение вычистить так что бы его и в менеджере задач не осталось, аналогично как его через этот самый менеджер закрываешь..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте `finishAffinity()` - метод закрывает все Activity в стеке. Правда, минимальная версия API - 16

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать через `system.exit(0);`

Comment: работает :)  но почему-то в менеджере задач остаётся приложение, правда, раньше он показывал само окно приложения, уменьшенное, а сейчас просто прямоугольник прозрачный..

Answer (score 0):

Для API 21 есть функция `finishAndRemoveTask();`

> Call this when your activity is done and should be closed and the task should be completely removed as a part of finishing the root activity of the task.

На практике же закрываются активности и приложение удаляется из стека, **но** включив профайлер я увидел что он не останавливается, а так же продолжает следить за приложением... По этому все равно приходится использовать `System.exit(0);` в конце.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    finishAndRemoveTask();
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    finishAffinity();
} else {
    finish();
}
System.exit(0);
```